# Shell script to convert specific column from binary to decimal

Tags: linux, shell, binary, sh

I have following lines repeating in text file. could anybody help me to convert 5th column items from binary to decimal. I want to edit the existing file without creating new file.

```
-117.894687      33.663901   0.000000    0,0,0   1010000000000000000000000000000000      1637.10     238.88      1719.04
```

Comment: Have you looked [here](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/65280/binary-to-hexadecimal-and-decimal-in-a-shell-script)?

Comment: you will always create a new file when you edit an existing one. If you were doing this in a text editor, the new file would be created in `/tmp/` and when you write the final file  back to disk, the old file is deleted. Also, just think about the size changes you are proposing. Either you replace `1010000` with 312 (or whatever) followed by spaces, or you put a newline at the end of your substitution, which will shorten the length of your file. Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

```
#!/bin/bash
bin=1010000000000000000000000000000000

echo "The decimal value of $bin is $((2#$bin))"
```

Now in-order to break the above string and send it to this file you have to use `cut` command and the make the above shell script executable using `chmod +x binconv.sh`

Then send the cut command through the command line and change the above script according to it

`bash binconv.sh 1010000000000000000000000000000000`

modify `bin=1010000000000000000000000000000000` to `bin=$1`